# Compare png files pixel by pixel

Tags: compare, png, pixel

I need some code that will ask names of 2 input files(windows explorer), then compare pixel by pixel. Files must have same specs. If value is same, move pixel to new output file. If value is >, move the > pixel over.
At end save output file as newfile.png
New file must have EXACTLY same specs as input files. These are gray scale images, no color.

Haven’t tried anything . Need help. I’m not coder

Comment: So after reading some Java articles, I can use BufferedImage to read pixels, but then with ImageIO.write, I loose the CRITICALLY important PNG headers info. Can someone pls AT LEAST confirm this?

Comment: Eventually wrote my own code